# Limit length of backreference in Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a rather complex regular expression that matches a few strings. As part of the requirement, I need to replace some of the matching text with a truncated version. Using a backreference I get the text, but how do I use "string".replace() to truncate it e.g. only the first 10 characters? As there may be multiple matches per string, I do not want to manually extract and truncate the text.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript 1.3 it's possible to pass a function as the replacement argument:

```
s = s.replace(/someregularexpression/g, function(x){ return x.substr(0, 10); });
```

[(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: This also applies to whatever versions of JScript are in IE 5 and later. In short, this works in all major browsers.